# After clicking on add to cart Lotus Breath - One Step Checkout hanges. It keep loading for a long time

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, override-model

To   Bypass cart and go to checkout  i used these files

app/etc/modules/Maddy_Cart.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Cart>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Checkout/>
        </depends>
        </Maddy_Cart>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Maddy/Cart/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maddy_Cart>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Maddy_Cart>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
                <observers>
                    <maddy_cartbypass_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Maddy_Cart_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>afterAddToCart</method>
                    </maddy_cartbypass_observer>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/community/Maddy/Cart/Model

```
<?php

class Maddy_Cart_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
{
    public function afterAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $response = $observer->getResponse();

        $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
    }
}
```

There is no error in console.

Comment: I think you have wrong code in file **app/etc/modules/Maddy_Cart.xml**

Comment: Sorry , i posted same code two times here

Comment: I tried the same code and I am able to redirect to checkout page. There is no error. Can you check your log files for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Maddy_Cart.xml is wrong,You should define here

- **`module` name and**
- **it `codePool` and**
- ***its active status* `true/ false`**

Here you have ***missed codePool ad active status***

also you have written,*the code of your module's config.xml*.You need to remove this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Maddy_Cart>
                <codePool>community</codePool>
        <active>true</active>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Checkout/>
        </depends>
            </Maddy_Cart>
        </modules>
       </config>
```

Comment: i updated my code is still there is an error.

Comment: It works on fresh magento but doesn't worked when I used same code in a custome theme.